# Phonegap - select options "selected" via JavaScript

Tags: cordova, selection, local-storage

Given the following **html** code:

```
<body onload="loadSett()">
<form id="settingsForm" name="settingsForm">
    <select name="Sound" id="Sound">
        <option value="0">Off</option>
        <option value="1">On</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Vibration" id="Vibration">
        <option value="0">Off</option>
        <option value="1">On</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
```

I have the following **javascript**:

```
var getSound;
var getVibra;

function loadSett() {
    var form = $("#settingsForm");
    getSound = localStorage.getItem("sound");
    getVibra = localStorage.getItem("vibra");

    if(getSound != undefined && getVibra != undefined) {
        if(getSound == "1"){
            document.getElementById('Sound').options[1].selected = true;
        }
        if(getVibra == "1"){
            document.getElementById('Vibration').options[1].selected = true;
        }
    } else { alert("Empty"); }
}
```

**Problem:** Why the the **option** of select tag is not ***selected*** on load the page according the value stored in localStorage? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the basics of your code. Maybe check the console output for errors, etc.

Here is a jsbin version of your code that works as expected: http://jsbin.com/uwucib/1/edit

Comment: i've checked the localstorage, it has values 0 for "sound" and 1 for "vibra"... but on load the page both are "off" that is 0